# Xcode iPhone app package missing files

Tags: iphone, xcode, file, package

I'm struggling to figure out what exactly it is that decides which files go into the .app-package when compiling an application in Xcode. I've noticed that most image files go there automatically, while others like yaml-files or psd don't, and I cant find anywhere to set this. So, how do you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the build phases for your application target. You'll find that recognized image files were added to the Copy Bundle Resources phase. To copy files of a type that Xcode doesn't recognize, you can add a Copy Files build phase.

If all else fails, [read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/200-Build_Phases/bs_build_phases.html).

Comment: When adding a file, Xcode asks you for which targets the file should be included. One can always right click on the file > get info at a later time to add it to a specific target, or just drag it to the target in the menu.

Comment: After almost two years, I'm not surprised. Probably still findable with a search on developer.apple.com...